# Haskell: how to match list of integers to indices of string

Tags: string, list, haskell, indexing, functional-programming

I have a very long string and two list of integers, the first one represents the left-starting index and the second list represents the right-ending index for substring within list.

To better illustrate this is an example:

```
String = "Lorem ipsum (dolor) [sit] amet, {consectetur} adipiscing elit"
List1 = [12,20,32]  -- starting indices
List2 = [18,24,45]  -- ending indices
```

and the result should be: `["(dolor)","[sit]","{consectetur}"]`

thank you!

Comment: Are the lists guaranteed to be sorted? What have you tried? I'd start by `zip`ping the lists then traversing with recursion.

Comment: no, not necessarily, is there some way where I can by using guards check whether they are sorted in ascending order and if not - print message using putStrln and exit the program?

Comment: voting to close because there was no attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can zip the two index lists together and use them to map a substring function (lambda with take and drop using the indices):

```
substrings s l1 l2 = map (\(i1,i2) -> drop i1 (take i2 s)) $ zip l1 l2
```

Although I think your first and second closing example indices are wrong for the expected result. Usage:

```
> substrings string [12,20,32] [19,25,45]
["(dolor)","[sit]","{consectetur}"]
```

Comment: Although short and simple, this approach is quite slow for large strings as the substring function has to repeatedly iterate through the start of the string.

Comment: or `take (i2+1) ...` to leave the OP indexing as it is.

Comment: @WillNess sure, that would work for the first two, but the third would be off by one then.

Comment: @WillNess When I left my original comment OP had not yet said that the indices aren't sorted.

Comment: @Aplet123 I don't think it's possible to go asymptotically faster than this and still use `String`s as the input and output types.